# How to convert '10-OCT-17 07.57.14.253290000 AM' text into date format '2017-10-10 07:57:14'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I want to convert `10-OCT-17 07.57.14.253290000 AM` date format into `2017-10-10 07:57:14`

and

`10-OCT-17 12.57.14.253290000 PM` date format into `2017-10-10 12:57:14`

and

`10-OCT-17 07.57.14.253290000 PM` date format into `2017-10-10 19:57:14`

I want **AM** and **PM** should come into consideration .

```
cast(to_timestamp(pub_ts ,'dd-mon-yy HH.MI.SS') as timestamp without time zone)
```

Where pub_ts is a text. I have used this 15 days back through this would work.

It converts

`10-OCT-17 12.57.14.253290000 PM` date format into `2017-10-10 00:57:14`

Comment: is it text or actual timestamp?..

Comment: and where do you want to convert them? in your mind? in your app? what language?

Comment: Plus, what have you already researched & tried yourself on this? “I want” is not a _question_.

Comment: @VaoTsun text  .

Comment: @N.lvanov inside the postgres.

Comment: @CBroe .added in question.

Comment: You forgot to include the `AM` placholder in your format mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you just [need a right mask](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)? EG:

```
postgres=# with e(v) as (values('10-OCT-17 12.57.14.253290000 PM'),('10-OCT-17 12.57.14.253290000 AM'))
select v,to_timestamp(v,'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.US000 AM')::timestamp(0) from e;
                v                |    to_timestamp
---------------------------------+---------------------
 10-OCT-17 12.57.14.253290000 PM | 2017-10-10 12:57:14
 10-OCT-17 12.57.14.253290000 AM | 2017-10-10 00:57:14
(2 rows)
```

Comment: `12.57.14.253290000 PM` means `12.57.14` why 00:57:14 result coming ? and also i am getting same result for AM.  one should be `12.57.14` and other ` 00:57:14` if i write AM and PM at last.

Comment: But AM and PM output should come different ? both coming 00:57:14

Comment: my bad - a typo

Comment: Appreciate the effort .